# images getting cut off in flexslider carousel

Tags: carousel, flexslider

I using the woothemes flexslider with the carousel below the slides and the when clicking on the next arrow, it seems like it is not moving over enough and will cut off the images. It worked fine when I only had 7 images, but once I added two more images this is when the issue appear. Is there something I need to do differently in my CSS?

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2399619/walmart-careers/event-past-description.html

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Debbie